# layout should take size of background image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in designing of android and I know I am not good in it, but here is the thing , what I want to do is some thing may be simple or may be not possible , i am setting the background of the layout which is used under the relative layout 
such as

what I want is i want my layout fill parent in width and it should take the height as the background height is , I do not want to scale and I also do not want to set height in dps, also for some reasons I do not want t add imageview set image in it and then wrapping the height of layout .

So is there any way to do this ?

Comment: So set the relative height as wrap_content, width as fill_parent and set the background targeting the image whatever that you have.

Comment: but its compressing the view , but if i set image  into a imageview and then if i set the height to a wrap content then it shows better

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img_bg_wood">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/nine_man_morris"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```